# find files based on name and moving them with renaming simultaneously

Tags: command-line, find, rename, mv

Consider I've directories named according to years and containing pdf files according to subject-code.

`ls` output is:

```
$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 May-June-2011
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Nov-Dec-2011
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 20:36 Summer-2012
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Summer-2013
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Summer-2014
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Winter-2012
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Winter-2013
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Apr  8 08:52 Winter-2014
```

Each directories contains pdf files according to subject-code:-

```
ls -l May-June-2011/
total 808
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 104193 May  1  2011 161901.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 103380 May  1  2011 161902.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 115664 May  1  2011 161903.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  88953 May  1  2011 161904.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 179268 May  1  2011 161905.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 116158 May 24  2011 161906.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 106033 May  1  2011 161907.pdf
```

In other words each directory has `16190{1..7}.pdf`

---

Now suppose I want to move all (from all directory mentioned) `161901.pdf` to a specific directory (say `xyz`) with renaming to it's parent folder's name.pdf.

Explanation :-

Here is list of all `161901.pdf`:

```
$ find -name 161901.pdf
./May-June-2011/161901.pdf
./Nov-Dec-2011/161901.pdf
./Summer-2012/161901.pdf
./Summer-2013/161901.pdf
./Summer-2014/161901.pdf
./Winter-2012/161901.pdf
./Winter-2013/161901.pdf
./Winter-2014/161901.pdf
```

I want that `./May-June-2011/161901.pdf` should be moved into `xyz` with new name `May-June-2011.pdf` (name of directory inside which file is). i.e move `./May-June-2011/161901.pdf` to `./xyz/May-June-2011.pdf`

Similarly `./Nov-Dec-2011/161901.pdf` to `./xyz/Nov-Dec-2011.pdf`, `./Summer-2012/161901.pdf` to `./xyz/Summer-2012.pdf` and so on (up to `./Winter-2014/161901.pdf` to `./xyz/Winter-2014.pdf`).

The expected output for `ls xyz` is:

```
$ls xyz
May-June-2011.pdf
Nov-Dec-2011.pdf
Summer-2012.pdf
Summer-2013.pdf
Summer-2014.pdf
Winter-2012.pdf
Winter-2013.pdf
Winter-2014.pdf
```

---

How can I accomplish this? (how to `find -exec` or with loop or something else)

Comment: great, looking for the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found  `while read -r line` very helpful and I've succeed with following command:-

```
find -name 161901.pdf | while read -r line; do mv $line ./xyz/$(echo $line | cut -d "/" -f 2).pdf; done
```

Explanation:-

- Here `find -name 161901.pdf` list the founded files (already mentioned in question) which piped to `while` loop in while path stored in variable `line`.
- `cut -d "/" -f 2` filters the directory name e.g-`May-June-2011`
- And finally `mv $line ./xyz/$(echo $line | cut -d "/" -f 2).pdf` moves files (with renamed to directory name in which they were)

So, `find`+`while`**loop** with `mv` using `cut` for naming accomplishes what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Perl module [Unicode::Tussle](https://metacpan.org/release/Unicode-Tussle) comes with a very useful script named [rename](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/Unicode-Tussle-1.11/script/rename) (which is unfortunate, because the name clashes with the standard `rename(1)` on Linux).  With it, you could do something like this:

```sh
mkdir xyz
find . -name '*.pdf' -print0 | \
    rename -0 's!^\.!xyz!;  s!/[^/]*\.pdf$!.pdf!'
```

Without Perl, you could still do the same thing with a bit of shell plumbing:

```sh
mkdir xyz
find . -name '*.pdf' | sed 's/^/mv /' >src
find . -name '*.pdf' | sed 's!^\./!xyz/!; s!/[^/]*\.pdf$!.pdf!' >dest
join src dest | sh -
rm -f src dest
```

And, as I'm sure other people will be quick to point out, you can even put it on a single line, using `<(...)` process substitution.  I'm not sure that would make things more legible though.  Computers these days are powerful enough to allow a more verbose syntax. ;)

Comment: +1: cool - I didn new about Uncode::Tussle kit. (In perl.deb package you get `prename` a not so unicoded variant of rename)

Comment: Aside from being Unicode-aware, the great thing about `Uncode::Tussle`'s `rename` is that it can use full Perl substitutions.  It's a huge time saver in many situations.

Comment: I agree!!. prename is the same thing. (it is in face a 20 line very readable perl script)

Answer (score 2):

`find` is rarely useful when you don't need to traverse a directory tree recursively. Here a simple loop and shell wildcards are enough.

```
for x in */161901.pdf; do
  mv -- "$x" "xyz/${x%/*}.pdf"
done
```

Or, with the Perl-based `rename` command on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives (`prename` on Arch, not the Linux `rename` command on other distributiosn):

```
rename 's!/.*!!; $_="xyz/$_.pdf"' */161901.pdf
```

Or, with zsh:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(*)/161901.pdf' 'xyz/$1.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `find -print` and pipe the filelist to `awk` where you can transform it to whatever you want, e.g. a `cp` command:

```
$ find -name 161901.pdf -print | awk -v TARGET=xyz -F'/' '{ printf "cp %s %s/%s.pdf\n", $0, TARGET, $2; }'
cp ./May-June-2011/161901.pdf xyz/May-June-2011.pdf
cp ./Nov-Dec-2011/161901.pdf xyz/Nov-Dec-2011.pdf
```

and this can then be piped to a shell to get executed:

```
find -name 161901.pdf -print | awk -v TARGET=xyz -F'/' '{ printf "cp %s %s/%s.pdf\n", $0, TARGET, $2; }' | sh
```

Comment: I appreciate your use of `awk`!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible solution. The argument of the script is the directory in which you are searching, and now it is just printing what will do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -type f -name '161901.pdf' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do
    # get folder name
    d="$(basename "${f%/*}")"
    target="${d}.pdf"
    echo cp $f "xyz/${target}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweet and simple:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find . -name 161901.pdf | while read -r line
do 
  # this will create new filenames e.g. ./May-2013/161901.pdf will be now May-2013-161901.pdf
  filename=$(echo $line | grep -oP "\/\K.+$" | sed 's/\//-/g')
  # now just move the files
  mv $line xyz/$filename
done
```

So, essentially it's just a 2-step process. Create new filenames and move 'em.

Comment: Thank-you for reminding `while read -r line`!

Answer (score 0):

If you have **rename / prename** command

```
find -name 161901.pdf -exec prename -n 's!/!-!g; s!\W*!xyz/!' {} +
```

and remove `-n` if you like what you see.

(Larry Wall and Robin Barker' prename is installed with perl.deb package; Brian d Foy `Unicode::Tussle` rename also works)